# convert IP address to mac address cmd

Tags: batch-file, arp

I have found a lot of answers to this question, but not for batch.
here's what I got.

```
C:\Users\Colton>arp -a

Interface: 192.168.1.12 --- 0xb
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.1           74-44-01-42-aa-df     dynamic
  192.168.1.11          20-7c-8f-3f-03-9b     dynamic
  192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.0.253           01-00-5e-00-00-fd     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

I just need to get the Mac address of a givin IP address on its own.  I think the findstr command is what I need, but I don't know how to use it.

I would then set that as a variable with this command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('command_that_I_need') do set "macaddress=%%A"
echo the mac address of 192.168.1.11 is %mac%.
```

I have no Idea how to Parse out the Mac address from the arp command, as that is all I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
set "ip=192.168.1.11"
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('arp -a ^| findstr /b /l /c:"  %ip% "') do set "mac=%%a"
echo %ip% = %mac%
```